# Open Link In java without Visual

Tags: java, php, mysql, netbeans-7, openurl

i have 1 mysql server and i need to open 1 page to change values.
i dont need to read,because the page is updating values from table.
How to open a link,without design or browser,to page send command to database?

in c# unity,i'm using :

```
WWW www = new WWW( "http://saidmrn.link.com/Insert.php");
```

Very thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$www = file_get_contents("http://saidmrn.link.com/Insert.php");
```